# Is it possible to change the date format from 2/6/2020 to 6 February 2020 in SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I would just like to know if it is possible to change the date format in my SQL Database from d/m/yyyy to 6 February 2020

Here is the code I have but don't know if it is possible and what I would need to add:

```
"SELECT Id, filename, datestamp FROM FileTable WHERE filename like 'COPY RECON%.xlsx'"
```

The datestamp is where the date and time is being saved.

Thanks

Comment: I would keep the date as DateTime and change it where it is shown on the web-page (assuming, since also tagged in asp.net). I woujld not convert the DateTime to string with the query since then the date format can ever be changed by changing the query - which would not allow to do you something locale specific.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, so how would I go about changing it on the web page?

Comment: This is what I have now `<asp:BoundField DataField="datestamp" HeaderText="Date" />`

Comment: Check the possible formats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy} if I am not mistaken

Comment: @KeithKing that's the fix, not the explanation. Change the *field type* to `datetime` or `date` and load it as a `DateTime`. ASP.NET will format this using the request's culture. This can be hard-coded, or come from the *browser's* language selection. Worst case, you can hard-code the format on a control or a call to `DateTime.ToString()`

Comment: @KeithKing dates have no format, either in SQL Server or .NET. They are binary values. This isn't nitpicking - there's no way to tell what 04/07/2020 means. Is that April 7 or July 4th? If you store strings you can easily store the wrong date or invalid dates that will cause your code to crash. Finally, localized strings can't be ordered or filtered by a date range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment as answer :-)

I would keep the date as DateTime and change it where it is shown on the web-page (assuming, since also tagged in asp.net). I woujld not convert the DateTime to string with the query since then the date format can ever be changed by changing the query - which would not allow to do you something locale specific

So assuming asp.net the correct format should be

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="datestamp" DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" HeaderText="Date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL SERVER, then below script might help you

```
SELECT  FORMAT(CAST('02/06/2020' AS DATE),'dd MMMM yy')
```

This will give you

```
06 February 20
```

Comment: Going with GETDATE() instead of CAST('string' AS DATE) would have been easier mate

Comment: @RAHULSR the question isn't how to return the current date, it's how to convert a date literal to another format.

Comment: last time i checked Getdate() is still a date literal ...all i said was it would have been easy to convey the nsg

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT Id, filename, FORMAT(datestamp,'dd,MMMM,yyy') FROM FileTable WHERE filename like 'COPY RECON%.xlsx'
```

the above answer is for your knowledge that you can do it in server side aas well but

dont do it would be my answer ...well to be perfectly clear all your view related changes formats, and every other thing should be done in your presentation Tier that would be your apps controller part or in your front end part

UPDATE : Its not Invalid

[image]

Comment: This is invalid syntax. And even if it's fixed, that's not the date format in the question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  i might ask which part if you mean dd MMM yyy it may cos i am typing from mobile but the function is there mate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: And it's invalid.

Comment: ya which part is my question